# In TortoiseSVN, how do I find the revision when I deleted a branch?

Tags: tortoisesvn

There is lots of info about how to recover a deleted folder, but they all seem to say use SVN command line and "go to the revision before you deleted the folder".

Our processes did not record the revision of the delete.

With numerous very active developers and dozens of branches, it will take some time to hunt through the logs to find the revision.

What is the best way to get the revision?

Answer (score 1):

**CLI-version, SVN 1.7**

`svn log URL-OF-BRANCHES-FOLDER -q -v | grep -B 2 "D /URL-OF-BRANCHES-FOLDER/BRANCHNAME"`

Sample:

`svn log http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/branches -q -v | grep -B 2 "D /branches/Greetings"`

```
r17 | lazybadger | 2010-07-17 05:09:40 +0600 (Сб, 17 июл 2010)
Changed paths:
   D /branches/Greetings
```

**CLI-version, SVN 1.8**

Use added `--search` OPTION, first revision in log (I can't combine `--search` with `-l 1`)

`svn log URL-OF-BRANCHES-FOLDER -v --search BRANCHNAME`

Sample:

```
>svn log http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/branches -v --search Greetings
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r17 | lazybadger | 2010-07-17 05:09:40 +0600 (Сб, 17 июл 2010) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   D /branches/Greetings

Finished and integrated feature-branch
...
```

**TortoiseSVN**

- Repo-broswer for repository URL
- Log for branches URL
- Enter string with branchname (with leading slash) of part of name in filter-string
- Find the latest revision

[image: Filtered log]

Comment: My question is how to avoid the serious amount of work involved in executing the step "Find the latest revision"

Comment: @BrianLeeming - for me solutions 2 and 3 are "fast&easy" (and Win-friendly)